# C unit test framework that supports mocking nested functions

Tags: c, unit-testing, mocking

I'm looking for a unit testing framework in C that supports mocking helper functions inside a function.

Example:
I have two functions, Function A and Function B both of which are in the same source file.
Function B is called from within Function A.
I'm looking for a framework that will enable me to mock Function B when called from Function A.

Currently we use cmockery but it does not support this feature.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 4):

We use Typemock Isolator++ since you don't have to change your production code.

See example:

```
void FunctionB()
{
            throw "error";
}

void FunctionA()
{
            FunctionB();
}

TEST_CLASS(GlobalCMethods)
{
public:
            TEST_METHOD(MockingGlobalFunction)
            {
                            FAKE_GLOBAL(FunctionB);
                            FunctionA();
            }
};
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I faked  FunctionB to ignore it's execution which is the default behavior of faking void functions.and the exception is not thrown. If FunctionB would have a return value, the default would have been returned (null, 0...). You can also set a behavior manually for instance make it throw some other exception or redirect the call to FunctionB to some other function with the same signature. There are some other cool stuff  you can read about in the docs http://typemock.com/docs?book=Ipp&page=Documentation%2Fhow_do_i_fake___.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the C preprocessor for this:

```
CALL(func)(...);
```

Usually, the macro expands to the argument

```
#define CALL(f) f
```

To enable mocking, use

```
#define CALL(f) mock_##f
```

Now every function call will be redirected to `mock_...` which allows you to inject code to divert the call to a mock or the real function.